# Email notification from ActionMailer using sendgrid when a user send a new message to another user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, sendgrid

I'm building an application where I tried using ActionMailer to trigger an email to a user when a message has been sent. The problem is that my code sends a message to the user who wrote the message and not to the recipient.

This is my message controller:

[image: This is my message controller]

Here's `mailer.rb`:

```
class ConversationMailer < ActionMailer::Base  
    def conversation_created(user)  
        mail(to: user.email,  
        from: "contact@uvesty.com",  
        subject: "You got a beloved message :D",
        body: "Hi, somebody has messaged you on"

    end
end
```

Comment: You are sending e-mail to current user. Get receipent from newly created message and pass this user to conversation_created method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to format your question so it's readable. Help is available in the entry box. Formatting is important because it helps us understand what you're asking, which speeds our answers to you, and it also helps others understand your question. Effort is good. Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages, along with "[mcve]". Please don't use a link to essential information. Links rot then break resulting in questions that make no sense. Instead, reduce the code to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable that selects the recipient user. Right now, you have it set to where `@user = current_user.`
The problem with this is that when you call user.email you are calling the `current_user`'s email address, not the recipient. You need to create a variable for the recipient user and call that `recipient.email`